# Why doesn't i2cdetect send any data over a secondary (dtoverlay=i2c-gpio) I²C bus?

Tags: i2c

I'm trying to add a second I²C bus to my Pi 3B by using two unused GPIO ports (BCM #6 and #26 resp. HW #31 and #37), so I added this line in `/boot/config.txt`:

```
dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,i2c_gpio_sda=6,i2c_gpio_scl=26
```

After a reboot, the second bus appeared under #11:

```
pi@autoradio:~ $ i2cdetect -l
i2c-1   i2c             bcm2835 (i2c@7e804000)                  I2C adapter
i2c-11  i2c             ffffffff.i2c                            I2C adapter
```

But the one and only device on the bus doesn't respond:

```
pi@autoradio:~ $ i2cdetect -y 11
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

So I tried to use a logic analyser to find out, which electrical signals are sent over the two wires. It seems as there was a clock signal, but apparently no data were transferred. Red is data (#6), and blue is clock (#26):

[image: Logic analyser output]

No data. Only silence on the red wire.

As I have installed the probes near the Pi (only the pull-up resistor attachments are on the way), and I have tried other pins as well, I can almost exclude a wiring problem. So: Why are no data sent over the wire?

**UPDATE:** `piscope` does show me some activity on SDA, but it seems not to go through the wire: [image: piscope output]

**UPDATE #2:** I've now managed to get a data signal on SDA (without really knowing why, unfortunately) as long as the TDA is disconnected from I²C:

[image: Logic analyser output with chip disconnected]

`i2cdetect` then runs very slowly (needs several seconds to probe the bus). As soon as I connect it, the logic analyser keeps on showing high level without any data flowing.

Comment: Not sure if the odd bus numbering requirement documented https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-PI-Multiple-I2c-Devices/ still exists.

Comment: It may not work at all until you enable pull-ups.  Have you enabled the internal pills for GPIO 6 and 26?

Comment: Hint: If you don't use a special HAT, you may use I2C bus 0 on pins 0 and 1 as well. This is a hardware bus, so it should work just fine.

Comment: @joan I'm using my own PURs, both @ 10k.

Comment: Use piscope to see what is happening at the Pi. http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html

Comment: Done. See above.